# Does Solaris 8 Support Connect:Direct Version 3.3.03

Tags: solaris, connect-direct

A Solaris 5.6 System is being upgraded to Solaris 8. We have Connect:Direct Version 3.3.03 installed. In the link [What versions of Connect:Direct are supported on Solaris 9](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21542556) we found that "Connect:Direct UNIX, Release 3.6.00 is supported on Solaris 8 or 9." Does this mean Versions below 3.6.00 is not supported or Versions below 3.6.00 are supported but not versions above 3.6.00.

Comment: The Solaris 8 support life ran from 2000 - 2014, and it's now well past end of support.  It's time to move off of Solaris 8, not on to it, especially if you want to find other users who still use it and can help you.

Comment: It's probably best to call Sterling about this.